# MS-DOS to make a batch execution of a command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I have 50 files with this naming convention:

```
myObject.0001.obj
...
myObject.0050.obj
```

I need to execute the following DOS command on those 50 files:

```
ply2vrmesh myObject.0001.obj myObject.0001.vrmesh
...
ply2vrmesh myObject.0050.obj myObject.0050.vrmesh
```

I have written the following .bat with my limited rusty MS-DOS knowledge:

```
for %%T in (*.obj) do ply2vrmesh %%T %%T.vrmesh
```

It works but it converts `myObject.0001.obj` to `myObject.0001.obj.vrmesh`. I would like to get a clean naming instead like `myObject.0001.vrmesh`, and i don't know how to do this.

If you guys have any idea it would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are modifiers for the FOR variables that extract specific info. The `~n` modifier gives the name without the extension. Type `HELP FOR` from the command prompt to get a complete list of modifiers.

You should enclose your filenames in quotes in case the name contains spaces.

```
for %%T in (*.obj) do ply2vrmesh "%%T" "%%~nT.vrmesh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just follow your existing command with:

```
rename myObject.????.obj.vrmesh myObject.????.vrmesh
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Jean-Francois it works perfectly , i need to use 2 batch files , but it works thats the most important ! Cheers E